# Uploadify v3: add a hidden input with the uploaded file's name

Tags: uploadify

I'm using Uplodify v3 and I want to add a hidden input with the uploaded file's name in it's value.

How can I do that?!

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
'onUploadSuccess'   : function(file, data, response) {
    $('input#yourhiddeninputid').val(file.name);
}
```

I tried and Work.